# Automatically create WiFi hotspot after boot

Tags: wifi, networking

Elementary allows for creation of WiFi hotspot in "network settings" menu. However, the Hotspot mode is turned off at every boot. How to make Elementary automatically create WiFi Hotspot at launch, if there's a WiFi adapter plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Network Setting` ==> `Hotspot` ==> check the button & configure it (by giving a `name` and `password` u want)

after that open `terminal` 
and write: `sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot`

Find the string: `autoconnect=false`
change it to: **`autoconnect=true`**

**save** and `reboot` to test if it works